# Como gerar campo auto incremento, no models do Django, que não seja PK, e que dependa de informações de outro campo que é FK?

Tags: django, autocompletar, auto-incremento

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Django que tem dois models, Modalidade e Licitação. A Licitação tem um campo FK (models.ForeingKey), que puxa a  Modalidade.
Eu gostaria que esse campo gerasse um valor automático, crescente (001,002,003) para cada Modalidade.

Desta forma, para:
a modalidade XXX eu posso ter licitação 001,002,003 .... 999
a modalidade YYY eu posso ter licitação 001,002,003 .... 999

E assim por diante, mas em cada modalidade essa numeração não de se repetir.

O código é mais ou menos esse:

```
class Modalidade(models.Model):
    modalidade = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Licitacao(models.Model):
    modalidade = models.ForeignKey(Modalidade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    licitacao = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    objeto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi da seguinte forma, aproveitando a ajuda do amigo Pablo:

class Licitacao(models.Model):
modalidade = models.ForeignKey(Modalidade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
licitacao = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.licitacao = Licitacao.objects.filter(modalidade=self.modalidade).count() + 1
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Continue with save as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

O campo com esta numeração não pode ser PK nem FK porque ele se repete. Mas se quiser usar um campo auxiliar para armazenar esta numeração ok. Supondo que o campo se chame "numeracao", a forma mais simples e evidente de se fazer isto é criar o objeto, calcular o campo e salvar. Veja o exemplo:

```
uma_modalidade = Modalidade.objects.get(id=123)
nova_licitacao = Licitacao(modalidade=uma_modalidade)
nova_licitacao.numeracao = Licitacao.objects.filter(modalidade=uma_modalidade).count() + 1
nova_licitacao.save()
```

Uma outra alternativa é fazer um override do método save, mas existem alguns porens que estão fora do escopo desta questão.

Comment: Este código é implementado em forma de função no Models, ou no Forms?